# Is there any API to fetch the battery status information into a windows 8.1 application

Tags: windows-8.1

You cannot vote on your own post 
0

we are developing a windows 8.1 application, where we need to show to the user the current battery status on the device. Since our application is running in access mode, user is not allowed to open the charms bar and check the device battery status.

Can somebody please help us, if any such API is present in windows 8.1 to fetch the battery status details of the device?

Is there any other way to retrieve this information and display to the user inside our application?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [Battery class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.phone.devices.power.battery.aspx)

Comment: Battery class is specific to windows phone. But we wanted similar API for windows store 8.1 application.